# Unable to navigate to any other file in intellij for karate tests

Tags: intellij-idea, karate

I want to jump to **landingPageLocators.json** file by click on *landingPage* in below line inside intellij IDE

```
Then waitFor(landingPage.mainHeading)
```

my **landingPageLocators.json** looks like below:

```
    { landingPage : {
          "mainHeading" : "//div"
         }
    }
```

It is very difficult to know from which file this code is coming inside feature file. In java we can easily navigate to file by clicking ctrl+click on file name.

Why don't it happen in karate tests. I am using IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This level of IDE support is not yet supported in the IntelliJ plugin. It is on the roadmap.

Comment: @PeterSmith This should be provided on priority because it is very hectic to manage large size project without file navigation feature. Can you please provide any tentative date or any alternative to it

Comment: @Yash in full transparency - when this is implemented, it will be a premium feature for paying subscribers of the plugin. if you are already paying for the plugin, let us know and we can get in touch to share more details